# I'm trying to find out what reports a user is subscribed to so I can create custom dashboards? How can I do this?

Tags: subscriber

I've been asked to create custom dashboards for our execs based on the reports they reports they're subscribed to. I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve a list of these items so I didn't have to ask them directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received a response form Salesforce and this functionality is currently not available.

If you'd like to vote for this follow this link below.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Do0VAAS